# Concatenate two infinite C# IEnumerables together in no particular order

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, ienumerable

I have two methods that each return infinite `IEnumerable` that never ends. I want to concatenate them so whenever any of the `IEnumerable`s return a value, I can instantly get and process it.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var streamOfBoth = get1().Concat(get2());
            foreach(var item in streamOfBoth)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
               // I'd expect mixed numbers 1 and 2
               // Instead I receive only 1s
            }
         }

        static IEnumerable<int> get1()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                yield return 1;
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<int> get2()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                yield return 2;
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to do this with IEnumerables without having to use threads?

Comment: Why do you need to block the current thread by `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: Can't write a full solution since I'm on my phone at the moment, but: you can call `.GetEnumerator` on each, and the `.MoveNext` method will return a boolean to tell you if it could advance to the next item.

Comment: Can you try something line

Random random = new Random();

while(true)
{
if(random == 1)
{
call1
}
else
{
call2
}
}

Comment: Your main thread got into an infinite loop. Consider using background threads instead and take a look at new C# feature called async yield.

Comment: @Soptikha A better alternative could be to use Rx.Net streams.

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be something for [Rx.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh242985(v=vs.103)).

Comment: An option would be the use of the Zip LINQ method: `foreach (var (item1, item2) in get1().Zip(get2(), (item1, item2) => (item1, item2)) { }`. This iterates over both enumerables at the same time and does a pairwise "concatenation" of both enumerables.

Comment: Are you sure that your sources are `IEnumerable`s? A better candidate for a streaming sequence is an `IAsyncEnumerable` or an `IObservable`. Both of these can be concatenated (merged is a better term) with LINQ-style operators [(1)](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Merge.cs) [(2)](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/Merge.cs).

Comment: Which thread do you imagine will be going to sleep when you get to `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly easily achieved with [`System.Reactive`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)

```
static void Main()
{
    get1().ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Subscribe(Print);
    get2().ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Subscribe(Print);
}

static void Print(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

static IEnumerable<int> get1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        yield return 1;
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> get2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        yield return 2;
    }
}
```

This produces the following output on my machine:

```
2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
```

Note that `ToObservable` is called with the argument `TaskPoolScheduler.Default`; just calling `ToObservable` without it will result in synchronous execution, meaning it will keep enumerating the first sequence forever and never get to the second one.

Comment: Cool technique, but just to be clear: this **will** run on multiple threads (from the thread pool).  And it's still unclear whether or not the asker is OK with that because the (unclear) question asks for a way to do this "without having to use threads".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to *interleave* `get1` and `get2` (take item from `get1`, then from `get2`, then again from `get1` and then from `get2` etc.). Generalized (`IEnumerable<T>` are not necessary infinite and of the same size) `Interleave<T>` extension method can be like this:

```
   public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {
     public static IEnumerable<T> Interleave<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                                params IEnumerable<T>[] others) {
      if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
      else if (null == others)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(others));

      IEnumerator<T>[] enums = new IEnumerator<T>[] { source.GetEnumerator() }
          .Concat(others
          .Where(item => item != null)
          .Select(item => item.GetEnumerator()))
        .ToArray();

      try {
        bool hasValue = true;

        while (hasValue) {
          hasValue = false;

          for (int i = 0; i < enums.Length; ++i) {
            if (enums[i] != null && enums[i].MoveNext()) {
              hasValue = true;

              yield return enums[i].Current;
            }
            else {
              enums[i].Dispose();
              enums[i] = null;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      finally {
        for (int i = enums.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
          if (enums[i] != null)
            enums[i].Dispose();
      }
    }
  }
```

Then use it:

```
   var streamOfBoth = get1().Interleave(get2());

   foreach(var item in streamOfBoth)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(item);
   }
```

**Edit:** if

> "*whenever* any ... return a value, I can *instantly get* and process"

is **crucial phrase** in your question you can try `BlockingCollection` and implement [producer-consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem):

```
static BlockingCollection<int> streamOfBoth = new BlockingCollection<int>();

// Producer #1 
static void get1() {
  while (true) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    streamOfBoth.Add(1); // value (1) is ready and pushed into streamOfBoth
  }
}

// Producer #2
static void get2() {
  while (true) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

    streamOfBoth.Add(2); // value (2) is ready and pushed into streamOfBoth
  }
}

...

Task.Run(() => get1()); // Start producer #1
Task.Run(() => get2()); // Start producer #2

...

// Cosumer: when either Producer #1 or Producer #2 create a value
// consumer can starts process it 
foreach(var item in streamOfBoth.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic `Merge` method that merges `IEnumerable`s. Each `IEnumerable` is enumerated in a dedicated thread.

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;

public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources)
{
    IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> observables = sources
        .Select(source => source.ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default));
    IObservable<T> merged = Observable.Merge(observables);
    return merged.ToEnumerable();
}
```

Usage example:

```
var streamOfBoth = Merge(get1(), get2());
```

Enumerating the resulting `IEnumerable` will block the current thread until the enumeration is finished.

This implementation depends on the [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) and [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) packages.